# Different translation and interpretations on Genesis 1:2, which one is more close?

Tags: torah-study

In Torah ([mechon-mamre.org](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm)'s version),the first half of the verse was translated "the earth was unformed and void, and darkness was upon the face of the deep", in the second half the word "מְרַחֶפֶת" has been translated "was hovering", but in ["recovered version" of the Bible](https://text.recoveryversion.bible/01_Genesis_1.htm), the first half has been translated "the earth **became** *waste and emptiness*, and darkness was on the surface of the deep", "מְרַחֶפֶת" has been interpreted as "was brooding", and further interpreted in [Life Study of Genesis](https://www.ministrybooks.org/books.cfm?id=220FA7) (Chapter 3 of 120 Section 3 of 7) that "G-d's original creation was damaged by Satan's rebellion and then judged by G-d Himself. After G-d's judgment, there remained nothing except darkness upon the surface of the deep water."(Which means such "damage and judgement story" happened between verse 1:1 and 1:2) Is this an acceptable interpretation? Did the author misunderstand the word and the context? I searched [a site here](https://context.reverso.net/translation/hebrew-english/%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%97%D6%B7%D7%A3) for reference, but can't draw any conclusions. I will be grateful for any help provided.

Comment: According to the medrashic interpretation (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%92 and https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%93) it would appear that the intention of the word *merachephes* is that God's spirit initially only hovered over the new world but would only find a home in the new world after man's efforts to welcome it.

Comment: Personally I found the medrashic interpretation makes more sense to me, but unfortunately my community accepted the latter one without giving the benefit of doubt, I tried my best to find clarity for fear that we're on the wrong path of accepting and understanding Lord the Blessed One.

Comment: Judaism does not believe that original sin has the ability to impugn the purity of God's creation.

Comment: There is a lot that doesn't fit a naïve read, "Bereishis" means "In the beginning of", but there is no natural "of what?" mentioned in the verse. "In the beginning of G-d [having?] created the heaven and the earth". "Unformed and void" also eludes intuitive understanding, because what was unformed if it was void? Or to use another translation, how can emptiness be in chaos? What was laid waste, if if was empty? There had to be something there that lacked all form (Ramban) or lacked a useful form.

Comment: According to Bereishis Rabba, v. 1 describes the creation ex nihilo. Before v. 2, other worlds were created and destroyed. So that at v. 2, G-d is starting the creation of our world, which was made of tohu vavohu -- however you translate that. According to Nachmanides, G-d created substance and in v. 2 started giving it form. And who knows how much time went on in between? Nachmanides uses the Greek word hyle, as in hyle and morph -- substance and form. (Which could be consistent with the midrash, although he doesn't explicitly write about earlier worlds and hyle assuming earlier forms....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, the Hebrew verse says

> וְהָאָרֶץ **הָיְתָה** תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ

הָיְתָה means "was" in the past tense, so the Mechon Mamre version is correct. (Many Christian translations were done by people with poor grasp of Hebrew grammar. In my personal experience, it is rare to see a quotation from the Bible translated correctly.)

As Ezra said, the idea that an angel could defy G-d is nonsensical in Judaism, as all angels are messengers of G-d's will. To quote the [book of Psalms](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et26a3.htm)

> 20 Bless the LORD, ye angels of His, {N}
> ye mighty in strength, that fulfil His word, hearkening unto the voice of His word.
> 21 Bless the LORD, all ye His hosts; ye ministers of His, that do His pleasure.

In addition, the sin of Adam, the Flood, and tower of Babel are all told at length. Would something as important as an angel rebelling and changing the world be left out of the text?

See also the beginning of the book of Job, where Satan makes requests of G-d and follows His orders.

Comment: They quoted book of Isaiah 14:12-14 to support the opinion that an angel like Satan can rebel G-d.

Comment: This is a classic case of Christians taking something out of context. The verses clearly say they are referring to the king of Babylon (Nebuchadnezzar), and verse 16 specifically calls him a man. The entire passage is using poetic imagery that is clearly non-literal.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) and [Ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) interpret the word to mean "hovering" or "blew across". ([1](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), [2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.2?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)) This is in line with [Targum Onkelos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Onkelos) which uses the Aramaic word [מנשבא](https://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Genesis.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), from the root word [נשב](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%A9%D6%B7%D7%81%D7%91.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Every Jewish translation of the Torah I have seen uses this interpretation, and even many non-Jewish translations do as well.

That being said, I do not see the practical difference between "was hovering" or "was brooding". In either case, the word is being used metaphorically; the Spirit of God is not physical and therefore the Torah merely brings words to attempt to describe what is happening.

As for the last part, about Satan's fall, etc. this is not a Jewish concept.

Comment: Ibn Ezra (and many others) understands the wind to be a literal wind, so brooding would be incorrect. In addition, wind cannot think or brood.

Comment: @N.T. In English we often say “a storm is brooding” so I think it makes sense even in the context of the Ibn Ezra.

Comment: In English, not Hebrew.

Comment: @N.T., yes, in the English of the translation. The translation could mean "brooding" in that sense. The figurative "wind" figuratively brooded, or blew, or... (the word also means spirit, although "Spirit of G-d" would also be figurative.) Except....

Comment: Except @ezra, I think the English idiom you are thinking of is "brewing"... When the whether is building to a storm, we often say "a storm is brewing."

Comment: @MichaBerger "Brewing" implies developing. The wind here was already strong.